# Hide Search Box if field is empty using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  if ($("#search").submit(function()) {
    {
        var x  = $(this).val();
        $.ajax(
          {
            type:'GET',
          url:'fetch.php',
          data:'q='+x,
          dataType:"text",
          success:function (data)
          {
            $("#here").html(data);
          }
          ,
        });
      }
    );
  }
  else if ($(this).find('#search').val() == '') {
    $("#here").hide();
  }

});
</script>
```

This Is my code for for searching but my search box field is not hiding when its empty. It is searching perfectly but still when i clear the text box it is still appears

Here is my css

```
#here{
      display: none;
      float: left;
      max-height:400px;
      width:300px;
      height:absolute;
      padding-left: 25px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      z-index: 9999;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: -1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      position:absolute;
      z-index:99;
      right:0;
      padding: 10px;
```

I dont know whats the problem
I'm Sorry if its simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have the if/else if block only running once, when you first load the code. Your check for whether the search box is empty needs to be added to some sort of event (perhaps a keyup event or a focus event?)

Comment: Yeah Right Now I'm Using This script 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
      $("#search").keyup(function()
      {
          $("#here").show();
          var x  = $(this).val();
          $.ajax(
            {
              type:'GET',
            url:'fetch.php',
            data:'q='+x,
            dataType:"text",
            success:function (data)
            {
              $("#here").html(data);
            }
            ,
          });
        }
      );
    });
    </script>
and its working for me for i don't know how to hide search box if its empty

Comment: You simply need to add your check for if the field contains content with a length over 0 inside your keyup function, right?

Comment: Yeah that's what i want

Comment: So put it in? You already have code to check for an empty string in the .val() in your original post and another user has kindly shown an alternative check using length :)

Comment: '$(document).ready(function(e){
      // var search = $("#search");
      if ( $("#search").val().length > 0 ){
      $("#search").keyup(function()
      {
          $("#here").show();
          var x  = $(this).val();
          $.ajax(
            {
            type:'GET',
            url:'fetch.php',
            data:'q='+x,
            dataType:"text",
            success:function (data)
            {
              $("#here").html(data);
            }
            ,
          });
        }
      );
    }
    });'
Is It Correct Pal ???

Comment: No, you are nesting the keyup event inside the check, not the check inside the keyup event! and you can check for yourself if it works

Comment: Thankyou So much Dude :))

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to check whether the textbox is empty you can use the following code as you check the length of the textbox:

```
 if ( $("#search").val().length > 0 ){
$("#here").hide();
}
```

but i really can't get what you want, could you please share your html and clarify more.

Comment: <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="search_box pull-right">
              <input type="search"  name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
                <div id ="here"></div>
      </div>
     </div>

Comment: $("#search").keyup(function() { 

 if ( $(this).val().length > 0 ){
    $("#here").hide();
  }
  });
check on jsfiddle i created  and your style css change display: none; to display: block;
https://jsfiddle.net/txt3ehwy/

Comment: Thankyou So much Dude